# Relation between characteristic classes and fundamental forms of a surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, characteristic-classes, low-dimensional-topology

I have an embedded oriented surface $M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. Is there a way to express it's Euler/Pontryagin classes using first and second fundamental forms of $M$? I would really appreciate a reference.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the Gauss-Bonnet formula?

Comment: yeah, but even if I express gaussian curvature using the first fundamental form, I still don't know how to connect it to characteristic classes + there is also geodesic curvature to deal with

Comment: Is your surface closed (compact and without boundary)? Otherwise, I cannot think of a reasonable answer.

Comment: In general, no, only orientedness is guaranteed. However I would be glad to get the result at least for closed surfaces. Ok, in this case, we can forget about geodesic curvature. What's next?

Comment: Then, as I said, just use the Gauss-Bonnet, expressing the Euler characteristic via integral of the curvature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $S$ is a closed oriented Riemannian surface. Then the [Gauss-Bonnet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) reads
$$
\int_S K dA =2\pi \chi(S). 
$$
Thus, one recovers the Euler characteristic from the 1st and 2nd fundamental form (in the case when $S$ is embedded isometrically in the Euclidean 3-space $E^3$). If you want to recover the Euler class $e_S\in H^2(S)$, this can be done as well:
$$
e_S= \left[\frac{1}{2\pi} KdA\right]. 
$$

For noncompact surfaces, I do not see any way to recover the Euler class (as an element of $H^2_c(S)$), since you can have an open surface realized as an open subset in a Euclidean plane sitting in $E^3$. In this case, the 2nd fundamental form is zero and, thus, all that you know is that you have a planar surface. Such a surface can have an arbitrary Euler characteristic $\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks! And Gaussian curvature is supposed to be recovered as $\frac{\operatorname{det}(Q_2)}{\operatorname{det}(Q_1)},$ where $Q_i$ is $i$-th fundamental form, right? Also, do you have any ideas on how to recover Pontryagin class?

Comment: Right. Pontryagin classes exist only in degrees divisible by 4, so they are meaningless in the case of real surfaces.